# Typescript: how can I extend interfaces with the same fields

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have two typescript interfaces I am trying to extend and they both have a `classes` field that is incompatible.

> Interface 'Props' cannot simultaneously extend types '{ classes: Record; innerRef?: ((instance: any) => void) | RefObject | null | undefined; }' and 'TypographyProps'. Named property 'classes' of types '{ classes: Record; innerRef?: ((instance: any) => void) | RefObject | null | undefined; }' and 'TypographyProps' are not identical.

How can I go about extending these? Can I choose one or the other or just rename one of them?

```
interface Props extends WithStyles<typeof styles>, TypographyProps {
   children: string;
}
```

Comment: Please provides the code in question and not only the error message. As such it's hard to see the issue

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [Mixins?](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is like 4 years late but just in case anyone also comes across this. I was trying to do the exact thing and opened a bunch of stackoverflow tabs talking about the same error message! Finally found a solution using aliases [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56085306/error-message-an-interface-can-only-extend-an-object-type-or-intersection-of-o)!

So in this case perhaps a solution would be:

```
type MultipleTypes = WithStyles<typeof styles> |  TypographyProps;
type Props = MultipleTypes & { children: string };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Omit<T>` to exclude `classes` of the type that don't align with your interface. I.e.

```
interface Props extends WithStyles<typeof styles>, Omit<TypographyProps, 'classes'> {
   children: string;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

TypeScript allows for a feature called [Mixins](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html), which looks like what you are basically doing. This will allow you to access multiple classes. However, you must create the definitions in two places. As you can see `c` implements `a` and `b` and it has to define all the types in both, but in `c` we don't need to add the logic to the functions just the name and the return type.

```
class a {
    public ax: number
}

class b {
    public bx: string
    public by(): void{
        console.log('by()')
    }
}

class c implements a, b { 
    public ax: number = 123
    public bx: string = 'hello'
    public by: () => void
}
```

The mixin then needs to be created (as we can see from the docs)

```
applyMixins(c, [a, b])

let myobj = new c()
myobj.by()
```

From the docs:

> This will run through the properties of each of the mixins and copy them over to the target of the mixins, filling out the stand-in properties with their implementations.

```
function applyMixins(derivedCtor: any, baseCtors: any[]) {
  baseCtors.forEach(baseCtor => {
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(baseCtor.prototype).forEach(name => {
      derivedCtor.prototype[name] = baseCtor.prototype[name]
    });
  });
}
```