# Error Message: "An interface can only extend an object type or intersection of object types with statically known members"

Tags: typescript

The following code:

```js
export type Partial2DPoint = { x: number } | { y: number }
export interface Partial3DPoint extends Partial2DPoint {
  z: number
}
```

Fails with the following error:

> An interface can only extend an object type or intersection of object types with statically known members.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 163):

### Types vs Interfaces differ in the ability to extend union types

(I'm answering my own question) This is because you cannot extend a union type using an interface. You must use type alias:

```js
export type Partial2DPoint = { x: number } | { y: number }
export type Partial3DPoint = Partial2DPoint & { z: number }
```

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52682220):

> A class can implement an interface or type alias, both in the same exact way. Note however that a class and interface are considered static blueprints. **Therefore, they can not implement / extend a type alias that names a union type.**

Comment: For those who struggled to spot the different, he changed `interface ... extends` to `type ... = ... &`

Comment: What if I wanted `{ z: number }` to be optional?

Comment: @huntzinger92 `{ z?: number }` makes `z` optional (`undefined`);
Essentially the same effect as in:
`{ z: number | undefined }`