# Class property type guard based on instance property value

Tags: typescript

How to make class example to infer `config` type based on `animalType` instance value check:

```
enum Animal {
  BIRD = 'bird',
  DOG = 'dog',
}

type Base = {
    id: number
}

// Object example
type Smth = Base &
  (
    | {
        animalType: Animal.BIRD;
        config: number;
      }
    | {
        animalType: Animal.DOG;
        config: string;
      }
  );

// type guards working
const smthObj: Smth = {
  id: 1,
  animalType: Animal.BIRD,
  config: 1
};

// should be error
const smthObj2: Smth = {
  id: 1,
  animalType: Animal.BIRD,
  config: 'x'
};

if (smthObj.animalType === Animal.BIRD) {
 smthObj.config = 1;
 smthObj.config = 'x'; // should be error
}

// How to make it work the same for class?

class myClass {
  id: number;
  animalType: Animal;
  // this should be based on Animal type
  // number for bird and string for dog
  config: number | string; 

   constructor(id: number, animalType: Animal, config: number | string) {
    this.id = id;
    this.animalType = animalType;
    this.config = config
  }
}

const smthClass: myClass = 1 as any

// I need to make only this check to work
if (smthClass.animalType === Animal.BIRD) {
 smthClass.config = 1;
 smthClass.config = 'x'; // should be error
}
```

[Typescript sandbox.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.5#code/KYOwrgtgBAgiCWECGAbKBvAsAKClAQgJIBKAIlALxQDkARvAE4Am1ANDnqQPIDilNTAPYBzNjgC%20OHABcAngAdgBJAGclVLLjxR4TAFxRwEWsAYSp2APSWoXWgCtgAY2lRgADyQR5KYDIVKAMoQ0gAW-PiqSgBkHFAAFHF4AD4YSdp4SAjIKAAqAQZwiKgAdERkANzpGU6CIABm8MIGRiYMVVoZkp1QqZoZGVnFeQWw2aXcPB0D2rUNTQYq0gzwIMLTA914AJQdONZQcopQwmBIzCpQAO6CDADWq8I4c0tQKiGhdvYGwWH8-Tp9FAAIzsLRDHL5RSFcYoMokUhgvBzRrNEESPZWGwqUKCMAoJhQExuBgMW7POqvd5hL4AJh%20H3%20cV0BlBcQhqChwBhw3hZCRUBRCxo7moGIs8HqCWpnwcJQ5I2OFGVY155VI2zSuBlXxKQuE-GB0x1cv1-GoooqUAOOLxBKJSlMZLM2G6%20xsAAlBFdDoIoMg7kp4K4bvdDqElCovEp6rdBShVCoAPwWJwJlSXCCyADC6cuAJZhkgbQ2Cq5PJyG31LWLpl6b2WjytBzC8EutvxhOJtCihLqqpyhwCFlmlOWYBct3ihdaplYUDLoyKOXn1aLxjrqSWKzWmoBeFbKhKun4ug2B9CbflsK5-EXinP4avZqo%20ri3Td2BerhlucTBizP8M0NBdLiyWQJSleJfzza9hlvZUqGXUp1T3DgYMTPU6lRQ1jQ%20ICjxfEVqGbbFcU7B0SWdCQgA)

Comment: @Behemoth scroll to the bottom `smthClass.config = 'x'; // should be error`

Comment: This might be interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56085306

Comment: Have you considered creating as many subclasses as animals you have (for example, one for Bird, another for Dog etc.) then setting type on config separately? It seems you're looking for Factory, but trying to implement through Unioning on class level; this won't work because of reasons described in the answer linked above.

Comment: @raina77ow it's a complex objection database model with multiple types and methods and only this property can be one of two types, so I hoped ts can somehow infer it in if block like for object example :( It's will be easier then just to check if config is number or string in if block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).

```
enum Animal {
  BIRD = 'bird',
  DOG = 'dog',
}

class myClass<T extends Animal = Animal> {
  id: number;
  animalType: T;
  config: T extends Animal.BIRD ? number : T extends Animal.DOG ? string : never; // this should be based on Animal type

  constructor(id: number, animalType: T, config: T extends Animal.BIRD ? number : T extends Animal.DOG ? string : never) {
    this.id = id;
    this.animalType = animalType;
    this.config = config
  }
}

const birdClass = new myClass(1, Animal.BIRD, 1);

if (birdClass.animalType === Animal.BIRD) {
  birdClass.config = 1;
  birdClass.config = 'x'; // should be error
}

const dogClass = new myClass(1, Animal.DOG, 'x');

if (dogClass.animalType === Animal.DOG) {
  dogClass.config = 1; // should be error
  dogClass.config = 'x';
}

const smthClass: myClass<Animal.BIRD> = 1 as any;

if (smthClass.animalType === Animal.BIRD) {
  smthClass.config = 1;
  smthClass.config = 'x'; // should be error
}

// Type guard function example for any class
function isBirdClass(smth: myClass): smth is myClass<Animal.BIRD> {
  return smth.animalType === Animal.BIRD ? true : false
}

function isDogClass(smth: myClass): smth is myClass<Animal.DOG> {
  return smth.animalType === Animal.DOG ? true : false
}

const unknownClass: myClass = 1 as any;

if (isBirdClass(unknownClass)) {
  unknownClass.config = 1;
  unknownClass.config = 'x'; // should be error
}

if (isDogClass(unknownClass)){
  unknownClass.config = 1; // should be error 
  unknownClass.config = 'x'; 
}
```

See it [in TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAgiCWECGAbKBvAsAKClAQgJIBKAIlALxQDkARvAE4Am1ANDnqQPIDilNTAPYBzNjgC+OHAGMUSAM7yoEAJ4BhOYoA8AFSjAAHgBdQTJXESp+F5CgB8GDlHhMAXFHARawBgG4nSAi2OioADsDuOv64UNKCIABm8MKR+sam5kGoAHREZFAA-B6Q3gxQqYYmIGawWSjZ3HxF8kYM8CDC5R7AAG4+vlAA9INQRgAW8EryY4JgKExQ3osKwAvxtZZoRmHAUjFxIC0MYNJGggwAFC7unqWsUIGbIeGR9wdJKVB6lRkbtrkkchFW4+LrfdLVTKbBq8QpQI7tTo3Xo+ACUjhieHGk2yLn4LmieCxE3k2UewR2-HJqGewEJROxpPeyX4zOETkk2E5MniLUWjCYGgUSioIGAAHdlOpNPILgBGe42HJ5Uj3OWo6I4eAJKAXejMIWKMl1WmUChUJX1FXorAxfWCmXZNn8OX0+2GpnxD78agGagDYbwmZzBZLHwMc4SPYHPlCYQe-hiyWqD3yxV1GE8e6+6gavba3Vxj3Gp6U80WjONG1OIuO51UV1DEbTWbzRbAfQMCMMGsiYv1mh+6Lc7AxozwiDjD3uFMyrSWgFkBwNh5KQIqTXYAsXeSTsbF6koU3lv7KwHVmK7qd1r0shv0q-7m+JO+D-1NoOt0Md8ORrl7QNTWEMAkGYKAEjAEBTngdZDCQCBQhQDsEnOB4QBUWIZRwCCoKMGCQGceR8AFVNHxnaVhVRdxH0IqUPXnDMVQcW08AYYAjDABgCMfEsKXCM0K2hFU4VaMAO3cBJUHkXZ-2wbDIOg9ZJlIPsZR3PdyI9KiJ3GWjZ2FBjoUaZinDYjiuJ0sZeJpMtzVPepGhE45xPAqSZJHMcoEggBrEBBHFEBpzomUXVXNCN3zHUriIki1J8vyAq0i88Hi-zAufb17ycVLEoy18cwDZtgzbMMuz-Edt2U1ThQuHL0so1EWK8kBfLS-tb06e8PxbEN207bsoGylqEvqo0BwKwauSAA).

**Note**:

- Using generics, you don't even need a type guard because the generics will automatically catch type errors.

Comment: thanks, updated answer to add any class validation with functions

Answer (score 3):

Class arguments should be a part of one data structure.

This approach is safe and easy

```js
enum Animal {
  BIRD = 'bird',
  DOG = 'dog',
}

type Base = {
  id: number
}

// Object example
type Smth = Base &
  (
    | {
      animalType: Animal.BIRD;
      config: number;
    }
    | {
      animalType: Animal.DOG;
      config: string;
    }
  );

// How to make it work the same for class?

class myClass {
  constructor(public props: Smth) {
    this.props = props;
  }
}

const smthClass: myClass = 1 as any

if (smthClass.props.animalType === Animal.BIRD) {
  smthClass.props.config = 1;
  smthClass.props.config = 'x'; // should be error
}
```

**UPDATE**

```js
enum Animal {
  BIRD = 'bird',
  DOG = 'dog',
}


// How to make it work the same for class?

type Either<R> = R extends Animal.DOG ? string : number;

class myClass<T extends Animal> {
  id: number;
  animalType: T;
  config: Either<T>

  constructor(id: number, animalType: T, config: Either<T>) {
    this.id = id;
    this.animalType = animalType;
    this.config = config
  }
}

const smthClass: myClass<Animal.BIRD> = 1 as any

if (smthClass.animalType === Animal.BIRD) {
  smthClass.config = 1;
  smthClass.config = 'x'; // should be error
}
```

Comment: nice solution, but my class is db orm model and it has separate props as in database